# create shared folder that works on linux device?

Tags: networking, mount, samba, directory

I'm new to Linux and trying to solve this problem

I have a hifi streamer with a removable 2.5' HDD running modified LMS server on top of some kind of Linux (musical fidelity encore). It has a default shared folder called `music` which is read-only so it can't be used to sync with my NAS.

I can remove that 2.5' drive from streamer and insert in to my PC running Ubuntu, but cant figure how to create new folder that is accessible from network (don't want to use default folder because it ruins my metadata). I can create folders, but when I put drive back in to streamer, I can't see them in network.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a wonderful use case for samba! Here's an official [turorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba#0) from the Ubuntu site. Additionally, [this](https://forums.slimdevices.com/showthread.php?106812-pCP-as-LMS-Server-with-Samba) forum post may be helpful(I'm not too sure what LMS is myself, but from your description, it seems to stand for logitech media server)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've used official tutorial to create smb share but after I've inserted drive back to streamer, LMS (yes, logitech media server) failed to start... Not sure what happened, but even when I removed smb folder, LMS starts only when drive is not inserted, maybe some kind of pretection?

Comment: That does sound odd... does LMS have any logs that it saves? The only thing I think of is that making it a samba folder changed the `chmod` permissions of the drive, making it unreadable by LMS, I've seen many issues online that samba permissions made something inaccessible, but I don't know why this would cause a task to fail/crash.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was out of the country for a few days... I've contacted tech support and they told me to bring device to the service center for firmware reflash... Dunno if it was caused by smb share or just a just a coincidence, but LMS failed to start so I couldnt get to the logs from web interface and there was nothing on ext drive... We'll see when device is back... anyway, thx for your time

Comment: Yeah, no problem, I hope it gets working soon. I don't know if it would run on a low-spec media box, but [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) might also be a plausible solution

Comment: it runs on atom e38xx cpu with 2gb of ram, shouldnt be a problem with power with syncing...